# Why I cannot save input-data to AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to save data which user input to local device by using AsyncStorage.
I followed some example of this like copy and paste and change a little.
Because I am junior engineer so I cannot understand completely mean of these code.

But I couldn't.

In addition to this, I dont want to use Redux.
Which one is wrong?

Following code is my code.

```
state = {
  fullname: '';
}

componentDidMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem('inputText')
  .then((value) => {
    if (value !== null) {
      this.setState({ fullname: value });
    }
  });
```

}

```
 handleOnpress() {
const db = firebase.firestore();
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/form1`).add({
  form1 : [
    { fullname: this.state.fullname },
 })
  .then(() => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render() {
 return (
   <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
     <InfoHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}>
       申請者情報１ 
     </InfoHeader>
     <Notes />
     <QuestionTextSet
        onChangeText={(text) => {
        this.setState({ fullname: text });
        AsyncStorage.setItem('inputText', text);
      }}
      placeholder={'例：留学太郎'}
      value={this.state.fullname}
      editable = {true}
     >
      姓名（漢字表記）
     </QuestionTextSet>
```

Comment: What is the error in console?

Comment: Your componentDidMount() can go into an infinite loop. As, once the component mounted, you will set the state. Which will again render, so again componentDidMount will be called and then set state...which can lead to infinite loop.

Comment: I have no Erro. Just I cannot see data which I input into some form after go back to other page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use,  `AsyncStorage.setItem('inputText', text);`
Maybe a catch error, undefined is not an function of callback in setItem function params.

So you should use `AsyncStorage.setItem('inputText', text, (e)=>{})`;

Once you want to storage an **Object**, then use:

`AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(object), (e)=>{})`;

And get it by:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key', (e, v) => {
      if (!e) {
        /**
         * your value 
         */
        const object = JSON.parse(v);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.
But now I can get item which I input into a form. I can check it on console.
However this item can be seen on a form.